# K массивов, порядка m×n

Tags: c++, c, массивы, память, malloc

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, как обращаться к элементу массива - матрице номер `k` размером `m×n`, например? к 3 элементу, 5 строки, 2 матрицы?
Память выделяю таким образом:

```
*buffer = (int*)malloc(((m*n)*sizeof(int))*k);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если считать от 0 - т.е. реально 2 матрица - это третья (нулевая, первая, вторая...) - то

```
buffer[2*n*m+5*n+3]
```

Answer (score 1):

В C99 можно сделать так:

```
typedef int my_matrix_t[m][n];
my_matrix_t *matrp = malloc ( ((m*n)*sizeof(int))*matr_count );

for (size_t k=0; k<matr_count; ++k) { // цикл по матрицам
  for (size_t i=0; i<m; ++i) {        // цикл по строкам
    for (size_t j=0; j<n; ++j) {      // цикл по ячейкам
       // какие-то действия
       matrp[k][i][j] = k;
    }
  }
}
```